# glGenVertexArrays causes a segmentation fault, how do I properly set up an OpenGL context?

Tags: c, opengl, glew, opengl-3

I'm trying to code a simple triangle.  However `glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID)` casues a segmentation fault whenever I run it.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);

SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

SDL_Event event;
SDL_bool quit = SDL_FALSE;

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID); // This causes crash
```

I found the exact same thing here [OpenGL Segfaults on glGenVertexArrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822184/opengl-segfaults-on-glgenvertexarrays) but

> I forgot to setup an OpenGL context. All fixed now.

doesn't help, as I believe I have already created an OpenGL context `SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);`.

How do I properly set up an OpenGL context?

Comment: Are you using [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) or [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/)? Both must be initialized.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I am using *GLEW*.  I have added `#define GLEW_STATIC` at the beginning of my code

Comment: So you're missing [`glewInit`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [Initialize GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html). Call `glewInit` immediately after creating the OpenGL context:

```cpp
SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    // error handling
    // [...]
}
```

Note, that [`glewInit`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) will return `GLEW_OK` f it was successful. [`glewInit`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) initializes the function pointers for the OpenGL functions. If you try to call the function through an uninitialized function pointer, a segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: Thank you.  That  definitly explains my problem.  `glewInit()` is actually not returning `GLEW_OK`.   So I'm going to see what else is going on

Comment: @Simon What is your OS? DO you bind the glew static or dynamic? See [GLEW - why should I define GLEW_STATIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741322/glew-why-should-i-define-glew-static/49741747#49741747)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.  I would assume dynamic since I installed it via `apt-get`.  I've also tried adding `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;` with no luck either

Comment: It seems setting `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` after `glewInit()` solved the problem.

Comment: @Simon No it does not. Calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` after `SDL_CreateWindow` doesn't have any effect. It's the same as not calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute`.